# Laravel: No public strings in classes?

Tags: php, laravel, function, class

i would like to set up some strings for further use inside the functions but Laravel just gives me a "Whooops"?!

```
class MyController extends Controller

{

    public $server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; <-----------------

    public function logger()

        {

            // do something

        }


    public function info()

        {

            // do something

        }
```

}

Even without the public it isn't working.

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: This has nothing to do with laravel..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class attributes may only be static values, so you can do this:

```
public $a = '123';
```

But not this:

```
public $b = $_SERVER['foo'];
```

If you want the latter, you'll have to set it explicitly in your constructor:

```
public $b = null;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->b = $_SERVER['foo'];
}
```

In recent versions of PHP (not sure where this capability started, maybe v7.0) you can also use expressions that equate to static values:

```
public $c = '123' . '456';
```